# Объединение данных таблиц по имени поля и значению поля

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста решение:
Даны представление и таблица, в представлении есть более 200 полей(проверка фл по многим критериям) с флагами да/нет, в таблице перечень наименований полей представления и нумерация. Необходимо создать процедуру для вывода количества проверок с флагом «да» по каждому полю за определённый период времени. Пытаюсь сделать с помощью курсора, где в качестве переменной вывожу названия полей(выборка значений из таблицы) в теле курсора беру сумму значений полей процедуры, принимая «да» за единицу, и вывожу переменную с именем поля. Как можно связать данные, чтобы показать , что имя поля t1=значению поля t2? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: назовите конкретную СУБД и приведите упрощенный пример  исходных данных и желаемого результата.

Comment: СУБД Microsoft sql server, добавила фото с исходными данными и желаемым результатом.

Comment: раз столбцов 200 штук, то динамический unpivot, либо через union-ы. либо мб как-то через xml можно

Answer (score 0):

вариант с `UNPIVOT` и динамическим SQL для версии sql server 2012. (*для более старших проще будет, можно XML не приплетать а использовать `STRING_AGG()`*)

В общем исходные данные в виде временных таблиц (*что ожидалось привести в вопросе, а не картинку ;)*)

```
use tempdb;

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#answers', N'U') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #answers;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#params', N'U') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #params;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#pvt', N'U') IS NOT NULL   DROP TABLE #pvt;
-- drop table if exists ... для 2016+

create table #answers (name varchar(10), f1 bit, f2 bit, f3 bit, f4 bit, f5 bit);
create table #params (title varchar(10), num int);
create table #pvt (name varchar(10), f varchar(10), v bit);

insert into #answers values
    ('fio1', 1,0,1,0,1),
    ('fio2', 0,1,1,0,1),
    ('fio3', 1,0,0,0,1),
    ('fio4', 1,1,0,0,1);

insert into #params values 
    ('f1', 1),('f2', 2),('f3', 3),('f4', 4),('f5', 5);
```

Делаем выборку из `#params`, и склеиваем имена параметров в строку

```
declare @fields varchar(max);    

select @fields = stuff(
                (select  ',' + title from #params for xml path(''))
                , 1,1,'')
PRINT @fields;
```

получаем строку `f1,f2,f3,f4,f5`

формируем динамический запрос

```
declare @upvt varchar(MAX) = 'INSERT INTO #pvt SELECT name, f, v FROM #answers UNPIVOT (v FOR f IN (' + @fields + ')) as unpvt';
PRINT @upvt;
```

получаем запрос вида

```
INSERT INTO #pvt 
SELECT name, f, v 
FROM #answers 
UNPIVOT (v FOR f IN (f1,f2,f3,f4,f5)) as unpvt
```

и выполняем его

```
EXEC(@upvt)
```

смотрим что там у нас в `#pvt` и получаем искомый результат

```
select * from #pvt;

SELECT f, sum(cast(v as INT))
FROM #pvt
INNER JOIN #params ON (#pvt.f = #params.title)
GROUP BY f, num
ORDER BY num
```

результат:

```
f          
---------- -----------
f1         3
f2         2
f3         2
f4         0
f5         4
```

в конце не забываем дропнуть временную таблицу (`#pvt`).

зы: будет забавно если ваша вьюха с 200 столбцами сделана с помощью pivot-а и можно было обратиться к первоисточнику.